# Are these roughly interchangeable: "you don't touch the ball with your lips", "you don't touch your lips to / onto the ball"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

The word "**touch**" is very flexible

> **[touch](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/touch)** 1 FEEL [transitive] to put your hand, finger etc. on someone or something
>
> She reached out to touch his arm.
>
> If your house has been burgled, you shouldn’t touch anything until
>   the police arrive.
>
> ‘Don’t touch me!’ she yelled.
>
> **touch somebody on the arm/leg etc**
>
> A hand touched her on the shoulder.

---

> **[touch something to something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/touch-something-to-something)**
>
> ***literary*** to move something so that it reaches something else with no
>   space between the two things
>
> She touched the handkerchief to her nose.
>
> He touched his lips to her hair.

[The Ngram says](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=touch%20it%20with%20your%20lips%2Ctouch%20your%20lips%20to%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctouch%20it%20with%20your%20lips%3B%2Cc0)

It found "**touch it with your lips**", but not "**touch your lips to it**"

Are these roughly interchangeable?: "**You don't touch the ball with your lips**", "**you don't touch your lips to / onto the ball**"?

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your question to highlight the word **literary** in the definition that uses **to**.

**literary** in a definition means that the expression is not used in normal conversational English, but is used in writing for literary effect... ie to create a particular atmosphere, rather than to convey meaning.

Looking at the two sentences you quoted:

> you don't touch the ball with your lips
>   you don't touch your lips to / onto the ball

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but only the first one would ever be used in normal conversational English.

The second sentence uses a literary turn of phrase, but starting a sentence with **you** is certainly not literary. The sentence would not sound natural in any situation- either spoken or written.

Answer (score -3):

No - you don't "touch *to*" something. Touch means direct contact with something, so it needs no direction. You might *reach out to* something in order to touch it, but once contact is made, that's it - you're touching it!

You might say instead:

> You don't *put your lips to* the ball.

Touching something *to* something else is idiomatic, but it tends to describe a gentle touch - hence your example of someone touching their lips to someone else's hair. In my opinion as a native British English speaker, it doesn't seem right in the context of a ball.

Comment: Why in the dictionary "He touched his lips to her hair."

Comment: what about "don't touch the ball with your lips", is it a common expression in that situation?

Comment: @Tom, see my answer.

Comment: @Tom I've added some detail - what I said was regarding the use of "touch to" as in "reach to" or "go to". You can touch something to something else but it doesn't seem to fit your example.